# How to display webp image in html (locally)?

Tags: html, webp

I wrote some basic code to display a webp image on html but it doesn't show up on Chrome.  Can it only be run on a server?  Do I need to link some kind of files to make it work?

```
<img src="img/img.webp">

<picture>
   <source srcset="img/img.webp" type="image/webp">
   <source srcset="img/img.png" type="image/png">
</picture>
```

Comment: Do neither work? It should work fine locally as well as on a server. Also, where are the images currently residing?

Comment: I guess the regular file structure:  index.html and then an img folder.  If I open index on Chrome, where the image is supposed to be is blank.

Comment: What happens if you right-click the src in inspect element and open in new tab?

Comment: You can use mamp and they will show up